# simple react works with npm start but not with nohup npm start &

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux

I tested with a simple app generated by

```
npx create-react-app myfirstreact
```

It works fine with

```
npm start
```

but if I try to run it in the background with

```
   nohup npm start &
```

I get

> Starting the development server...
>
> events.js:174
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
>
> Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, read Emitted 'error' event at:
> at lazyFs.read (internal/fs/streams.js:165:12)
> at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:467:17) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! myfirstreact@0.1.0 start:
> `react-scripts start` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed
> at the myfirstreact@0.1.0 start script. npm ERR! This is probably not
> a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /home/jglickman/.npm/_logs/2020-10-06T04_43_39_480Z-debug.log

Comment: Have you tried solutions provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604176/error-ebadf-bad-file-descriptor-when-running-node-using-nohup-of-forever

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. I tried them just now. The accepted solution  I thin kdoesn't apply to me, since this simple app only uses imports. Would I need to put __dirname on the imports? Here are some of my other attempts:

jglickman@devapp01:~/git/test/myfirstreact$ node src/App.js
/home/jglickman/git/test/myfirstreact/src/App.js:1
import React from 'react';
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Did you tried other solutions? like running in parenthesis and running it like `nohup node server.js </dev/null`

Comment: Hi. Here are the results: 

`joshua@joshua-KVM:~/git/test/myfirstreact$ node server.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/joshua/git/test/myfirstreact/server.js'
joshua@joshua-KVM:~/git/test/myfirstreact$ cd src
joshua@joshua-KVM:~/git/test/myfirstreact/src$ node server.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/joshua/git/test/myfirstreact/src/server.js'
`

Comment: I believe this is because there is no such file as server.js :)

Comment: I figured out that I needed to run

nohup node scripts/start.js &

then that error no longer happens. Ty. If you put this as an answer, I will accept it.

I think it's because the server accepts keyboard input

Answer (score 0):

Try running it like this:

```
nohup node scripts/start.js
```

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604176/error-ebadf-bad-file-descriptor-when-running-node-using-nohup-of-forever) will help too.